# Why remove() method on Java Set does not work

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
    Set<Set<Integer>> groups = new HashSet<>();

    for (int[] edge : edges) {
        Set<Integer> match1 = null;
        Set<Integer> match2 = null;

        for(Set<Integer> group : groups) {
            if(group.contains(edge[0])) match1 = group;
            if(group.contains(edge[1])) match2 = group;
        }

        if(match1 != null && match1 == match2) {
            result = edge;
        }else if(match1 != null && match2 != null && match1 != match2) {
            match1.addAll(match2);
            groups.remove(match2);     <---- This does not remove match2 from set
        }else{
            Set<Integer> newGroup = new HashSet<>();
            newGroup.add(edge[0]);
            newGroup.add(edge[1]);
            groups.add(newGroup);
        }
        
        .........
    }
```

The `groups` is a Set of Set of Integers.

However, the groups.remove(match2) method does not remove the set of integers from the groups.

What happened here?

Comment: Storing mutable things (like other sets) in a hash set is usually a bad idea...

Comment: The brute way is  to write an Implemantation of Set<Integer> with a hash function returning a static value and the usual eqauls function. This would be slow but should work, since all sets are placed in the same bucket of the super set.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting the [`Set` interface documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a set to contain itself as an element.

You are violating this rule when you mutate `match1` with the `addAll()` call while it's still inside the outer `Set`. The mutation causes the hash code to change without the outer `Set` knowing about it, so the inner `Set` is now in the wrong hash bucket and can't be found when you try to remove it in some subsequent iteration.

As a workaround, you can remove it, then call `addAll()`, then add it again. Internally, this will cause it to be placed in the correct hash bucket for its new hash code.

---

By the way, it looks like you're implementing a connected component detection algorithm. You can do that more efficiently using a [disjoint set forest data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). There's some good pseudocode in [How to store each set in a disjoint set forest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22012195/14637).